# Why do I get cannot set properties of undefined error

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to give font Size to all of my `<li/>` elements but I get an error and I don't know why.

**Error:**

> error is : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'fontSize')

Here is my code, please help me in your known

```html
<ul id="task-list">
  <li class="task">Gorev1</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev2</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev3</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev4</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev5</li>

</ul>

<script>
  let sonuc;

  let taskList = document.getElementsByClassName("task");

  for (let task in taskList) {
    let i;
    i++;
    taskList[task].style.fontSize = "50px";
    taskList[task].style.color = "red";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: ```for(let i =0; i< taskList.length; i++){
   taskList[i].style.fontSize="50px";
       taskList[i].style.color="red";  
}```

Answer (score 0):

your for loop is wrong. Try this:

```
for (const task of taskList)
{
    task.style.fontSize = "50px";
    task.style.color = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you absolutely need to use javascript for your case (and please, feel free to comment under this answer if that's the case), but I think you could achieve the same result by using css.

```css
.task {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="task-list">
  <li class="task">Gorev1</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev2</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev3</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev4</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) does not only return indices but also some extra properties which make your data invalid.

You can verify all values in `in` loop by `console.log` like below

```html
<ul id="task-list">
  <li class="task">Gorev1</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev2</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev3</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev4</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev5</li>

</ul>

<script>
  let sonuc;

  let taskList = document.getElementsByClassName("task");

  for (let task in taskList) {
    console.log(task)
  }
</script>
```

In your case, your loop has been stopped at `length`.

```
taskList['length'].style.fontSize = "50px"; //invalid, we don't have index for 'length'
```

You can use [`of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead

```html
<ul id="task-list">
  <li class="task">Gorev1</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev2</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev3</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev4</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev5</li>

</ul>

<script>
  let sonuc;

  let taskList = document.getElementsByClassName("task");

  for (let task of taskList) {
    task.style.fontSize = "50px";
    task.style.color = "red";
  }
</script>
```

Or a traditional loop with `i`

```html
<ul id="task-list">
  <li class="task">Gorev1</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev2</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev3</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev4</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev5</li>

</ul>

<script>
  let sonuc;

  let taskList = document.getElementsByClassName("task");

  for (let i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++) {
    taskList[i].style.fontSize = "50px";
    taskList[i].style.color = "red";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ul id="task-list">
  <li class="task">Gorev1</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev2</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev3</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev4</li>
  <li class="task">Gorev5</li>

</ul>

<script>
  let sonuc;

  let taskList = document.getElementsByClassName("task");

  for (let i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++) {
    taskList[i].style.fontSize = "50px";
    taskList[i].style.color = "red";
  }
</script>
```